# Create block over ajax Magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, controllers, ajax, json

I want to send block html in JSON response.

To be specific - I want to add functionality where customers are able to edit their addresses via Ajax requests. So the block class will be `\Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Edit` instance.

In Magento 1.x it will be just something like that:
`$this->getLayout()->createBlock('xxx')->toHtml()`

How to achieve similar things in Magento 2 ?

Am I doing it in proper way? Or maybe Magento 2 implements other ways of doing such things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-- `\Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory` to create the block.
-- `\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory` to return Json format.

```
/**
  * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory
  */
protected $layoutFactory;


/**
  * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory
 */
protected $resultRawFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory
    .....
) {

      $this->resultRawFactory = $resultRawFactory; 
      $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
      parent::__construct($context);

}

public function execute() {

$layout = $this->layoutFactory->create();

$block = $layout->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('\Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Edit')
                ->setTemplate('Magento_Customer::address/edit.phtml')
                ->toHtml();

/** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw $resultRaw */

$resultRaw = $this->resultRawFactory->create();
$resultRaw->setContents($block);

//$this->getResponse()->setBody($block); <= We also can use setBody.

return $resultRaw;

}
```

Comment: You need to remove `->getLayout()`, since you already have a layout.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting Interceptor error with Khoa solution , here is what worked for me:

```
  protected $resultPageFactory;


/**
  * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory
 */
protected $resultRawFactory;

public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {

      $this->resultRawFactory = $resultRawFactory; 
      $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
      parent::__construct($context);

}

public function execute() {

    $layout = $this->resultPageFactory->create();



    $block = $layout->getLayout()->createBlock('Custom\Module\Block\Active')->setTemplate('Custom_Module::socialsignup/block.phtml')->toHtml();

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw $resultRaw */

    $resultRaw = $this->resultRawFactory->create();
    $resultRaw->setContents($block);

    //$this->getResponse()->setBody($block); <= We also can use setBody.

    return $resultRaw;

}
```